# Microsoft Edge Cache deletion using batch file

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge

How can i create a batch file to delete the cache file of Microsoft edge.

On the batch click, it should delete all the cache file and recent history of edge browser.
I have tried to delete the files manually, but i need a dynamic batch file, so that it can work on multiple systems.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you need to get it to work on multiple systems, first of all **the paths to each Edge profile folder are most likely to be different**. It is a necessary step to figure out the path before we make such a batch file.

Actually, you can delete them inside Microsoft Edge. Just go to **edge://settings/privacy** and find **Clear browsing data**. There you can choose what to clear. This is safer than clearing them locally.